# Is there a way to shorten nested for loops in python?

Tags: python, nested-loops

I feel like I saw somewhere that there was a shortened version of this.

```
  #
  for a in range(len(characters)):
    for b in range(len(characters)):
      for c in range(len(characters)):
        for d in range(len(characters)):
```

I need to be able to choose the amount of nested loops too... but if someone could just help with this first that would be great!
I have been trying to shorten it for a day now and I cant figure it out.
Please help!!

Comment: It's a bit late to change the question now.  Ask a new question instead, if you can't find an existing answer that satisfies you.